# setting list of columns to specific values conditionally R

Tags: r, data.table

I am attempting to set values within a list of columns to NA conditionally by sending the list through a custom function in R, but have not been successful. I have a few issues that I'm working through here- the first being that I am working with a variety of tables that may or may not have a specific column present.

I have gotten around this by doing the following:

```
variable_list<-data %>% select(one_of('first_name', 'last_name', 'mrn', 'born_on', 'gender', 'middle_name'))

I then try to convert this into a list that I can feed into my function:
variable_list<-names(variable_list)
```

This doesn't seem to be in the proper list format though.

I then want to feed it through a function that does the following:

```
for (col in variable_list){
data[col=="", col:=NA]
data[col==".", col:=NA]
}
```

However this portion of my code does not seem to function properly.

Comment: Did you mean `data[get(col) == "", (col):=NA]`  and so on?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the simplest approach: just use `fifelse` on the columns. Note that I've restricted the operation to character columns (since those are the only ones where such an operation makes sense). If your operation is more general, you may need to amend the `is.character(v <- ..` logic:

```r
variable_list <- c('first_name', 'last_name', 'mrn', 'born_on', 'gender', 'middle_name')

for (col in variable_list) {
  if (is.character(v <- .subset2(data, col))) {
    set(data, j = col, value = fifelse(v %chin% c("", "."), NA_character_, v))
  }
}
```

Comment: This is great! I can't seem to get my variable list into proper format to send it through this. Do you know how to extract the list of columns from my select(one_of( statement?

Comment: They're just the names of the columns. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to solve your problem:

```
nms = c('first_name', 'last_name', 'mrn', 'born_on', 'gender', 'middle_name')

cols = intersect(nms, names(data))

data[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, \(x) fifelse(x %chin% c("","."),NA,x)), .SDcols=cols]
```